# Can I tell ReflectionClass constructor to be case sensitive?

Tags: php, reflection

I have encountered a very interesting problem. I have two classes: `APISession` and `ApiSession`. I have an API class as well, which has a method, like this:

```
public static function request($category, $name, $params) {
    $params["Response"] = new APIResponse();
    $class = new ReflectionClass("API".$category);
    return $class->getMethod($name)->invoke(null, $params);
}
```

I am calling the method:

```
$result = API::request("Session", "Check", array());
```

Naturally, I expect this to execute the `Check` method of the `APISession` class, however, I receive the following problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPErrorException' with message
>   'Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Method Check does not
>   exist'

I have checked the source of the problem and it is caused by the fact that the `request` is reaching `ApiSession` instead of `APISession`, despite the fact that the string passed to it is `"APISession"`. My question is: is it possible to tell the `ReflectionClass` constructor to be case-sensitive?

Comment: It's not possible to declare class with same name, even if different case. So either way only one class is loaded, and which one it is depends on the class autoloader.

Comment: That is sad news. I believe we should be able to create a class FooBar and another class Foobar. However, if that is the case and you can show me some reliable sources stating this, then I will have to accept this as a fact.

Comment: I'm sure it's mentioned somewhere, but quicker is to try it: `php -r 'class APISession { } class ApiSession { }'`

Comment: Thanks, Marek, you have convinced me. Can you write an answer so I can show my gratitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names are case insensitive in PHP, this can be demontrated by executing this on command line:

```
php -r 'class APISession { } class ApiSession { }'
```

Comment: Nice one, Marek, thank, hopefully other people will see your short and useful answer in the future.